# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str - Dash app

Tags: python, pandas, dashboard

Within the Dash code I have

```
 dcc.Store(id='store-data', data=[], storage_type='memory')
```

Where I created and stored some variables.

Later, I used a callback to calculate some results based on the stored data.

The stored data returns a dictionary and looks something like this:

```
dict_values = {
         'Value A':[1,2,3],
         'Value B': [4,5,6],
         'Value C' :[7,8,9],                 
       }
```

Now, within the callback that has as input the stored data I tried to create a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_values['Value A'])
```

That's when I get the error *TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str*

Does anyone know why and how can I fix it?

I have to mentioned that even thou I've got this error, Dash app still runs and works without any problem.

Comment: dict is a reserved word in python. try to rename your 'dict' to something else

Answer (score 0):

rename your dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
d = {
         'Value A':[1,2,3],
         'Value B': [4,5,6],
         'Value C' :[7,8,9],                 
       } 
pd.DataFrame(d['Value A'])
```

```
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

Comment: my bad. I called my dictionary dict in this example, but it has a different  name. I just changed it